# How to separate rows with different number of columns into another file using vim commands or sed/awk commands?

Tags: awk, vim, sed, grep

I have a data file in which some rows have 15 columns whereas some have 9 columns. I need to separate this file into two files. One file containing rows with 9 columns and another containing rows with 15 columns. Can anyone help me to do this. I have tried few 'awk' commands, but did not work. I have attached an image of my data file here[data.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVWaI.png).

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add 3 simple things in your question.1st- Sample of input, 2nd- sample of expected output, 3rd- your efforts in form of code which you have put in order to solve your own problem, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Without looking at your data,

```sh
awk '{print > (FILENAME "." NF)}' infile
```

will create 2 new files, `infile.9` and `infile.15` (and more files if there are records with different numbers of fields.

- `FILENAME` is an awk builtin variable holding, unsurprisingly, the current filename.
- `NF` is an awk builtin variable holding the number of fields in the current record.
- string concatenation in awk has no special operator, you just place 2 (or more) strings or variables side-by-side.